# plot without border (like hist) in r

Tags: r

If you call function `hist` on r, you will note that the box that usually surrounds plotting region doesn't appear, instead, only rulers indicating plot scale appear on the bottom and on the left. If you use r a lot you may probably have noticed this already. my question is: there is some graphical parameter or workaround to make this happen on any other plot of basic r (like in a scatterplot, a line plot, a qq plot or whatever)?

The only parameter I found was `axes`, but setting it to FALSE makes it disappear not only the box, but also the rulers.

Comment: Are you only interested in base ```R``` solutions or is ggplot relevant too?

Comment: base please. I'm convinced you can do it with base r so i would rather use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is bty graphical parameter:

```
 x= matrix(rnorm(100), ncol= 2)
 plot(x, bty= 'n')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `box()`.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

hist(mtcars$mpg, sub="w/o box")

hist(mtcars$mpg, sub="w/ box")
box()  ##  <-- this

par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. looking into box() documentation I found the answer